# Error Invalid principal in policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

This is my bucket policy.i am getting Error Invalid principal in policy error in the below policy. why it is coming whats wrong with the policy?

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity AJDNXHS78E5DD4DF41FD5"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue and finally found I was using the wrong access identity string,
You could get the correct identity from the Original Access Identity tab in the Cloud front section

You could also use the CanonicalUser as an option.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

Answer (score 1):

You can experience this issue if you create the CloudFront Origin Access Identity and update the bucket policy within the same script. There seems to be a slight lag between receiving a response from `aws cloudfront create-cloud-front-origin-access-identity` and it actually being usable as a principal. I imagine you can call something else to poll the status of that but I settled for a crude `sleep` before updating the bucket policy.

Answer (score -1):

This "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity AJDNXHS78E5DD4DF41FD5" is not a valid ARN e.g. fo IAM users, format should be "arn:aws:iam::account-id:user/user-name", not sure why you are using cloudfront instead of account number. Looks like you are trying to give permission to cloudfron origin identity, please use the sample policy mentioned here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: The best way is to check you Policy here : https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Comment: These don't look like most ARNs, but they are valid CloudFront Origin Access Identity ARNs.  See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/ for an example.